# MYSQLI Prepared Statement White Page

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I am trying to convert some PHP code for notifications into a more suitable Prepared statement. No matter what I try, it breaks my page. Is any body out there able to tell me where the error lies?

**EDIT** The page is not completely blank. The page breaks after this code.

```
$acctNotsQry = $redoDB->prepare('SELECT message, nDate FROM notifications WHERE uID = ? AND nSeen = "0" ORDER BY nDate DESC');
$acctNotsQry->bind_param('i', intval($memID));
$acctNotsQry->execute();
$acctNotsQry->store_result();
$acctNotsQry->bind_result($notMessage, $notnDate);

if($acctNotsQry->num_rows == 0){
    echo '<li><div class="nilNots">NO NOTIFICATIONS</div></li>';
} else {
    while($acctNotsQry->fetch()) {
        ?>
        <li><i class="fa fa-bell"></i> <?php echo htmlspecialchars_decode(stripslashes($notMessage)); ?>
        <p><?php echo date('d M Y - h:ia', strtotime($notnDate)); ?></p></li>
        <?php
    }
}
$acctNotsQry->close();
```

**SECOND EDIT:** The following code DOES work, the above does not. It might help with a solution:

```
$acctNotsQry = 'SELECT * FROM notifications WHERE uID = "'.$memID.'" AND nSeen = "0" ORDER BY nDate DESC';  
$acctNotsRes = $redoDB->query($acctNotsQry);
$acctNotsNum = $acctNotsRes->num_rows;
if($acctNotsNum == 0){
    echo '<li><div class="nilNots">NO NOTIFICATIONS</div></li>';
} else {
    while($acctNotsRow = $acctNotsRes->fetch_assoc()){
    $notMsg = $acctNotsRow['message'];
    ?>
    <li><i class="fa fa-bell"></i> <?php echo htmlspecialchars_decode(stripslashes($notMsg)); ?>
    <p><?php echo date('d M Y - h:ia', strtotime($acctNotsRow['nDate'])); ?></p></li>
    <?php
    }
}
```

I have tried searching for a solution to no avail.
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: white page could mean syntax errors. Consult these following links http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php
and apply that to your code.

Comment: Sorry, it's not completely blank. it breaks after the code above.

Comment: what do you mean by "after the code"? check for errors like I said.

Comment: This code is called in my navbar to show notifications. Nothing else is displayed on the page after the notifications link in the navbar which is where this code is.

Comment: @NOJ75 If you check out the two links Fred-ii- posted, [`error_reporting(-1);`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) (and possibly [`ini_set('display_errors', 1);`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php)), PHP will tell you what's wrong. Post that error here if you don't understand it and need help with it :) Google is also very handy in such cases (there is probably no error you'll ever encounter that nobody have had before)

Comment: @Qirel - I am trying to but no errors are displaying.

Comment: I have updated the question with a block of code that DOES work. This was before I tried to optimize for prepared statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
$acctNotsQry->bind_param('i', intval($memID));
```

to

```
$acctNotsQry->bind_param('i', $memID);
```

The 2nd and following arguments to `bind_param` are reference parameters, so you have to use variables there, not expressions. You don't need to call `intval()` yourself, the `i` type in the first argument tells mysqli to convert it to an integer when sending it to MySQL.

Comment: Sorry for the delay.  That has fixed it. Thank you for that and thank you for explaining why. Very much appreciated.

Comment: There should have been an error message in the PHP log about a reference requiring a variable.

Comment: Searched for the error but can't seem to find it. I am using MAMP.